# Listing processes for a certain timeframe

Tags: linux, process, ps

`ps -fu username` lists all processes currently running.

Is there a way to list all processes that were running in a time period ? like, the ones that ran yesterday (and are no longer running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at something called [process accounting](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/acct.5.html). Note that this may involve a rebuild of your kernel.